# Allow certain characters only in the middle, end or beginning of the words without forcing certain length

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to restrict certain characters, especially `.` only to the middle of my regex matches. That is, I want to match `Node.js` but not `end.` or `.css`.

My current regex has the problem that it requires at least two letters to work:

```
[\w]+[\w\.']*[\w']+
```

You can also see that I want to allow `'` in the middle and at the end, as in `I'm` or `students'` (papers or other attribution).

The problem with this one is that single letter words are not matched, eg. `I`. How to fix that? Here's a testcase: https://regex101.com/r/hV9fQ5/1

Comment: I dont really get what you are trying to do can you be more specific
Is this is what you are looking for : `[\w]*[\w\.']*[\w']+`

Comment: _The problem with this one is that single letter words are not matched._ Obviously because you have two non-empty quantifiers (`[\w]+`). You have to use non-capturing group.

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want to do, an alternative solution would be to match all groups of `\S+`, then filter out the ones that match `^\W` or `[^'\w]$`.

Comment: I understand everything except for your example: `students' papers`? So spaces are allowed as well?

Comment: I will clarify using edit. I added papers to make it clear that students is attribution.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to properly match all your test-cases:

```
(?:^|\s)(?:[\w]+[\w\.']*[\w']+|\w)?(?=\s|$)
```

It first matches a line beginning or space character, then either your current regex or a single `\w`, and finally asserts that the next character is a whitespace char, or that the match is at the end of a line. This may not be the best answer; it keeps the leading space along with the rest, but this can be trimmed off. Here's a test with your examples: https://regex101.com/r/vL7dV4/1

Comment: This does not match `"I"`.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to accomplish what you want by breaking up your requirements into sections and taking care of each one of them.

> Want it to start with a `'` or a letter? `[']*[\w]`
>  Could have
>   multiple `.` in the middle? `[\.w]*`
>  Could end with a `'` or a
>   letter? `[\w]*[']*`

So you end up with: `[']*[\w]+[\.w]*[\w]*[']*`

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/hV9fQ5/4)

Comment: This matches `"end."`.

Answer (score 0):

In English what you want is "(1) a single letter, followed by (2) either a (2a) sequence of zero or more letters, OR (2b) a sequence of letters, period or apostrophe followed by a letter or apostrophe".

This translates directly into

```
/^(\w(\w*|[\w.']+[\w']))$/
   ^^                    (1)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (2)
      ^^^                (2a)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  (2b)
```

Use this as:

```
input . split(" ") . filter(function(word) {
  return word.match(/regex/g);
});
```

Comment: This is really good, but it has one catch: it only works when tested on a single word.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
\w+(?:['.]\w+)*'?
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC1nL2/1)

The main advantage of this construct is that consecutive dots and single quotes are not allowed.

*(if you want to allow the quote at the beginning, add `'?`)*

Comment: Nice, but this incorrectly matches the `test` in both `.test` and `test.`.

Comment: @ETHproductions: I think you have misunderstood the requirements *(that are a bit unclear)*.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the requirements (which say _not `end.` or `.css`_).